# gvfs-open error opening file

Tags: bash, terminal

I have a function defined in bash.

```
o(){ xdg-open ${1:-"`xsel -o|sed "s/\n.*//"`"}; }
```

Normally I select a file name in terminal, then press "o" and return key to open file.

But now I find the gvfs-open append current path, this leads to errors.

Eg, I select text "~/bin/tmp.json".

```
~/bin > o
gvfs-open: ~/bin/tmp.json: error opening location: Error when getting information for file '/home/eexp/bin/~/bin/tmp.json': No such file or directory
```

I remember it works well before. Maybe the xdg-open was called another program like gnome-open, and now changed to gvfs-open?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xdg-open is just a shell script ([see the source code here](https://github.com/sindresorhus/opn/blob/master/xdg-open)) that acts as a universal tool for all platforms.

Xdg detects your desktop environment and calls the corresponding app for you (gvfs-open for gnome3 , exo-open for XFCE, gnome-open for gnome2, etc.)

If your function worked OK before using i.e gnome-open you can call it directly to see if that works.

In your case if you call your function `o` without the path might work.

Seems something strange goes on with paths handling by gvfs-open.

Comment: I just don't want to force the gnome-open or sth else.

Comment: What you mean you don't want to force gnome-open? This is what xdg-open does - calls gnome-open (for gnome bellow version 3) and calls gvfs-open for gnome3. You can do it manually to see if it works like this. More over try to avoid relative paths (like ~) and use absolute paths to see if gvfs still gets confused with paths.

Comment: o(){ xdg-open ${1:-"`xsel -o|sed -e "s.^~.$HOME." -e "s/\ /\\\ /g" -e "s/\n.*//"`"}; }

Comment: Nice that this worked. Just for my info did you accept my answer and then you un-accept it?

Comment: lol - ok - all goodYou are not obliged to accept any answer if you don't want to - and yes one click accepts - second click un-accepts